# Bad request response when calling asp.net web api from android studio using genymotion

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-web-api, genymotion

I want to call a simple asp.net web api from android studio.
When I call web api from c# console or from browser, then everything is fine.
But when I call it from android application (using genymotion) I got "400 Bad request" exception.
Here are the web api, c# code, java code (My application).
I used the default api that is given by asp.net:

```
  public class ValuesController : ApiController
  {
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

and here is c# code that works fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response =
            client.GetAsync("http://localhost:31219/api/values").Result;
        string str = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

and here is the java code (app code):

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        HttpClient client  = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getReq = new HttpGet("http://10.0.3.2:31219/api/values");
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        Object result = new Object();
        try {
            result = client.execute(getReq,handler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Stick a break point in visual studio on return new string[] { "value1", "value2" }; line to see if you are even getting there. As you are calling using IP address, that might create some issue as its not on localhost.

Comment: No, I don't get there when I use break point. If I either change port number or the ip, I get "request refused" and not "bad request".

Comment: I am not sure how genymotion works but it seems like it can not connect to your api. Is there a browser on genymotion, try to browse that api endpoint in the browser and see what you get.

Comment: I tried to connect from genymotion's browser and I got "Bad request - invalid hostname", and if I stop my server and try to connect again to the server via the browser I got "connection refused", so I can say that the Ip is good, right?, do you have any more ideas? Thanks

Comment: "Bad request - invalid hostname" means genymotion can not connect with the server...where is this http://10.0.3.2:31219 hosted?

Comment: 10.0.3.2 is localhost of the genymotion, and I don't know much about it. But I found something new that can help, when I call my api from my browser (Pc browser) like "localhost:....." it works, and when I call it from the same browser like "127.0.0.1" I got "Bad request" again, is this telling anything?